# Writing a simple addition function that iterates

Tags: javascript, function

Need to write a simple function that takes any number > 0 and adds all integers between that number and 1 and adds them together.

Here is the code I am using:

```
function SimpleAdding(num) { 
  for (i=num; i=1; i--) {
    num = num+i;
  }
  return num; 

}
```

Comment: can you provide a sample run for your expected output?

Comment: Show us a sample output.

Comment: And what is your problem/question?

Comment: Hi everyone, apologies if I was not clear! First post, but no excuses.Gabor has me covered below. None the less, thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

```
function SimpleAdding(num) {  
 var temp = 0;

 if(num > 0)
  for (i=1; i<=num; i++) {
    temp= temp+i;
  }
  return temp; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do right now is add the numbers to your original one, also including the same number (adding it twice I guess). You should either ireate from `i = (num - 1)`, or make a new `sum` variable and put your values in there.

Also, your condition in the middle section of the `for` was problematic, as you were saying "do this for as many times, as long as i equals 1", but that actually never happens, as you eg. pass in 5, 5 != 1. Correcting the condition to `=>` will say "do this as long as the number is greater or equal to 1".

```
function SimpleAdding(num) { 
  var sum = 0;
  for (i = num; i >= 1; i--) {
    sum += i;
  }
  return sum; 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for breaking this down in language a total newb like myself can understand. This all makes perfect sense

Comment: Chase, glad it helped. If you found this answer overall helpfull and it solved your problem, don't forget to mark is the accepted answer. If you have any further questions regarding your original question, don't hold back.

Answer (score 0):

just one formula that you might be interested in:

```
function SimpleAdding(num) {  
    var temp = 0;

    if(num > 0){
        temp = ((1+num)/2)*num;
    }

    return temp; 
}
```

That formula will calculate the sum of numbers in the range of: `1..[value_of_num]` inclusively.